# Get current total price from cakephp controller function and change div content through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

so first of all my goal is this:
I have a sample store with shop cart. When I click on an item to be added to the cart this action would happen:
It would add the selected item into database and then update the current price of shop cart.
So far I have my shop cart adding the item to database and updating database new total price, but I am not able to then load the updated total price.

my ajax function

```
function add(item){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "epood/summa",
        success: function (data){
          $('#text').val(data);
        }
    });
}
```

my html

```
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="add(this.id)">add</button>
<div id="text"></div>
```

my controller function

```
public function summa(){
   --code to get the price from database--
   echo $price; //this equals the price im getting from database
}
```

My code for getting the price works fine, but I think the thing where I'm doing something incorrectly is how I call back the price from function into ajax. Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to achieve, ask any questions if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.val()` on a `<div>`. That function only works on `<input>` fields.

Try using `$('#text').html(data);`

Comment: Wow, this simple change made it work, spent so much time researching this. Im really surprised I didn't figure this out, well thank you alot anyway.